Can an equation with a norm be put into purely linear and quadratic terms?
I am attempting to use least-squares methods to estimate parameters in a cone function. I have the following equation of a single sided cone in $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 $:
\begin{equation}\large f(\vec{x}) = \vec{Φ}\cdot(\vec{x} - \vec{l}) - cosθ||\vec{x}-\vec{l}|| = 0 \label{eq:main}\end{equation}
... where parameters $\vec{Φ}=(φ_i,φ_j,φ_k)$ is a unit vector (i.e $||\vec{Φ}||=1$), and $\vec{l}$ is a real vector.

NB. the first part of the above equation defines a plane, and is therefore linear: $p(\vec{x})= \vec{Φ}\cdot(\vec{x} - \vec{l}) = φ_ix + φ_jy + φ_kz -
   \vec{Φ}\cdot\vec{l} = 0$

NBB. $f(\vec{x}) = p(\vec{x}) - cosθ||\vec{x}-\vec{l}|| $ which plots a single sided cone. The addition of the norm makes the function $f(\vec{x})$ non-linear


I wish to put $f(\vec{x})$ into the linear form $B\vec{x} + c = 0$, but as that does not appear possible, put $f(\vec{x})^2$ into the quadratic matrix form:
$$\vec{x}^\top A\vec{x} = 0$$
...where we would use homogenous coordinates $\vec{x} = (x,y,z,1)$ in the above case. This formulation would allow me to exploit least-squares algorithms. I ask the questions:

Is it possible for $f(\vec{x})^2$ to be formulated in a purely quadratic bilinear form, with the norm term $||\vec{x}-\vec{l}|| $ included in $f(\vec{x})$? If so, how is this done?  If there are no real solutions, are there methods where complex numbers can be used?

If it is not possible, as I suspect, are there devices that can be employed as a workaround?  For example, could $f(\vec{x})^2$ be formulated in a bilinear block matrix form like:
$$f(\vec{x})^2 = \begin{bmatrix}\vec{x}^\top & \vec{x}^{\top 2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}A&\sqrt B \\ \sqrt B & C\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}\vec{x} \\ \vec{x}^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
...where $\vec{x}^2 = (x^2, y^2, z^2)$

Lastly, if none of the above approaches has a resolution, what other optimisation approaches could be pursued for this problem?  Bearing in mind that geometrically, the problem concerns the intersection of 4 (noisy) cones to find a point.


Discussion note: Norms are not linear (e.g. almost always:  $\|x+y\|\neq\|x\|+\|y\| $ ), but they are quadratic (as far as I know), so I would have thought there is a least squares solution to the problem in hand.
